# I want to change image source on code behind, like theme

Tags: c#, wpf

I have images on my xaml. like these...

```
<Image Name="ImageTekSayfa" Source="Resources/Dark/teksayfa.png" Margin="2,0" MouseLeftButtonUp="TekSayfa_Clicked"/>
<Image Name="ImageFavorites" Source="Resources/Dark/favorites.png" Margin="2,0" MouseLeftButtonUp="FavoritesClick"/>
<Image Name="ImageSoruModu" Source="Resources/Dark/sorumodu.png" Margin="2,0" MouseLeftButtonUp="SoruModu_Clicked"/>
<Image Name="ImagePerde"  Source="Resources/Dark/tahta.png" Margin="2,0" MouseLeftButtonUp="PerdeClicked"/>
<Image Name="ImagePen" Source="Resources/Dark/kalem.png" Margin="2,0" MouseLeftButtonUp="DrawingClicked"/>
<Image Name="ImageEraser" Source="Resources/Dark/silgi.png" Margin="2,0" MouseLeftButtonUp="EraserClicked"/>
```

And I want to write my ImageSources like this and change all Source path easy on my code side. like this:

```
<Image Name="ImageTekSayfa" Source="Resources/{THEME_NAME}/teksayfa.png" Margin="2,0" MouseLeftButtonUp="TekSayfa_Clicked"/>

public String THEME_NAME="dark";

if(currentTheme="ligth")
THEME_NAME="light";
```

etc..

Answer (score 1):

Two possible methods:

1. ValueConverter - Store each "theme templated" source as a string in a resource
   dictionary and bind the Image Source using a custom implementation of IValueConverter that correctly populates the required Uri:

   ```
   <Image Name="ImageTekSayfa" Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource teksayfa}, Converter={StaticResource themeConverter}}" Margin="2,0" MouseLeftButtonUp="TekSayfa_Clicked"/>
   ```
2. Custom XAML Behavior - Create a custom behavior that can convert the "theme templated" source into the required Uri:

   ```
   <Image Name="ImageTekSayfa" Margin="2,0" MouseLeftButtonUp="TekSayfa_Clicked">
       <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
           <bhv:ThemeImageSourceBehavior Source="Resources/{THEME_NAME}/teksayfa.png" />
       </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
   </Image>
   ```

Comment: Ok. i did it with IValueConverter.
But i cannot change image after Form created.

Comment: How can i refresh form after change Theme name?
i cannot reload images. So everythings are static.

Comment: Did you set the resource in the resource dictionary?

Comment: Yes. I set resource in the resource dictionary. But doesnt effect anything. Images assigned when form create and nothing change if i set theme value.